# How do I start a server instance during Test::Unit integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, testunit

I'm working on a project that is setting up to use Selenium (*not* capybara) for integration testing. Eventually, the goal is to be able to use the same tests against a remote staging server and the local test server. Selenium requires an actual HTTP server to point to, how to I set up Test::Unit to start a server instance at the start of each test suite run and shut it down at the end?